# Problems with AUTH LOGIN in python SMTP server

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, smtp, gmail

I'm attempting to create a python script to send an email over smpt.gmail.com.  I am only allowed to use sockets.

Currently, I've got the script to successfully connect to the servers, declare StartTLS, and wrap my socket in SSL.  However, I'm having issues when attempting to authenticate with the server.

Here is my authentification code:

```
clientSocketSSL.send('AUTH LOGIN\r\n')
clientSocketSSL.send(base64.b64encode('USERNAME')+'\r\n')
clientSocketSSL.send(base64.b64encode('PASS')+'\r\n')
```

The response I get is

```
501 5.5.2 Cannot Decode response
```

So then the MAIL FROM command fails as I'm not properly authenticated.

I feel like this is a very easily solution, am I just using the auth login incorrectly?  I've been looking for two hours but haven't been able to find anything...

Answer (score 0):

It should work I tried myself with openssl:

```
OpenSSL> s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.gmail.com:587                                                 
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Inc, CN = Google Internet Authority
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=smtp.gmail.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=smtp.gmail.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2304 bytes and written 383 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
    Session-ID: 3A9E6D2BD679FD124B6772C91C74A5AFCEE7699A212D514FBC11710B684BDE31
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: D7B5B70090660B2359CFD8B82582033C16B569DEE6ACE1F6EB2CDD4E2042A613410B5E6DD07643664ABC33E8049547B8
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 100800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 63 53 11 b3 92 0d 59 63-15 90 58 10 84 f2 f7 6a   cS....Yc..X....j
    0010 - e8 4b b0 a8 41 0a 73 0e-41 ee 3c a0 ab 91 df df   .K..A.s.A.<.....
    0020 - f0 24 b5 08 18 7d cc 56-05 9b 05 f4 e5 57 23 1b   .$...}.V.....W#.
    0030 - e0 00 33 e6 61 11 6b a2-9e 05 32 bb a3 99 8f 64   ..3.a.k...2....d
    0040 - 50 2c 6c 3a 5f 46 d1 53-2d 2a 3f 6a 8d cd c5 c8   P,l:_F.S-*?j....
    0050 - 4e 0a 15 63 04 e7 4e a0-01 51 79 93 38 3c de 62   N..c..N..Qy.8<.b
    0060 - 75 76 7a 0e 1c fc 98 0f-04 b5 b2 59 2a 1e c3 e5   uvz........Y*...
    0070 - aa d2 f6 2b 36 8c b8 97-77 77 9e 77 37 a7 ed 12   ...+6...ww.w7...
    0080 - d5 85 30 d2 e8 42 67 e8-84 97 0a f2 b6 95 fd 2f   ..0..Bg......../
    0090 - e7 f2 de 0e                                       ....

    Start Time: 1354229935
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
ehlo
250-mx.google.com at your service, [188.79.92.35]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
auth login
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
MY_EMAIL_BASE64
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
MY_PASS_BASE64
235 2.7.0 Accepted
```